# Show me the index on the table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

**Problem Statement:-**

Given a oracle table name how can I find out whether there is any index being created on a particular column in that table?

I know its a very basic question, I am not that much familiar with SQL stuff so that's why having problem. So posting here if anyone can help me out?

Comment: Sorry, no time to answer, accounting for all the different cases was going harder than I started. One possibility is to query one of the data dictionary views user_ind_columns, all_ind_columns or dba_ind_columns. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1100.htm#i1577532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT index_name
  FROM all_ind_columns
 WHERE table_name = 'THE_TABLE'
   AND column_name = 'THE_COLUMN'
   AND index_owner = 'THE_OWNER';
```

This should tell you the name of any index on 'THE_COLUMN' in table 'THE_TABLE' with owner 'THE_OWNER'. The column may or may not be the only column in the index.

Become friends with the dictionary. It will help you!